# Converting DOS text files to Unix

Tags: text-processing, centos

I have a bunch of PHP scripts that are in DOS format (`vi` displayed `[noeol] [dos]` in the status line) and as expected they weren't usable.

I ran `dos2unix` over them to fix the line endins:

```
dos2unix index.php
```

but when I open the files in `vi` I still see `[noeol]` on the status line.

Upon checking them in vi's hex editor mode (`:%!xxd`) I don't see anything that jumps out at me.

In the original files the line ends looked like: `0x0D 0x0A`

If after running through `dos2unix` they look like: `0x0A`

I also checked to ensure that the last line of the file has a proper end of line and that's there too (`0x0A`).

What else could be causing this, should I worry?

I'm running CentOS 5.6 x64.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a newline to the end of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file)

Comment: @enharmonic - No, and why are you asking this on a nearly 12 year old question where I already accepted an answer and my problem is long since solved?

Comment: I flagged as a duplicate, and StackExchange (un)helpfully auto-creates a comment with that text, as if I asked it.

Comment: @enharmonic ah, that's an annoying behaviour and had forgotten about this. My apologies if I came across a bit short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Klox said, after `running dos2unix`, the remaining problem `vi` shows is the missing newline on the last line.

If you open the file in `vi` and save it, it will add the newline for you.

Or in a batch you can do the whole thing with `ed`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in <list-of-files-goes-here>; do
    ed -s -- "$f" <<<$',s/\r//g\nw' >/dev/null
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I knocked up a variation in that. Is dos2unix broken?

Comment: @Kev: i don't know, i consider it an un-useful tool, given many other methods exist to do the same, without installing nothing new.

Comment: I eventually did:  `vi +":w ++ff=unix" +":q" ${f}` in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

It is just warning you that you don't have an end of line (\n) on the last line.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked and it's there.

Comment: @Kev: when you save, `vi` insert the last line newline. Have you checked after saving?

Comment: Yes that works as does `:set ff=unix`, but I have over 200 files and wanted to batch convert them.

Comment: Use a shell `for` loop to run `echo >> myfile` on each file.

Answer (score 1):

DOS machines enter a carriage return at the end of lines (eol), it should look like this in vi `^M`.

Try running this:

```
:%s/^M//g
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `ed` to batch convert your php files since `ed` will add the missing final newlines for you as well.

Using `ed` there is no need for tmp files either.

```
# using Bash
IFS=$'\n'
for file in *.php; do
   ed -s "$file" <<< $'H\n,g/\r*$/s///\nwq'
   #printf '%s\n' H $',g/\r*$/s///' wq | ed -s "$file"
done
```

Comment: I would point out that I came to almost the same solution without seeing your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use vim (instead of an old skool vi), you can do this:

```
:set ff=dos
:e!
```

and you'll be able to edit the PHP files without all the ugly "^M" suffixes.  I believe it will save as a DOS "text file" format, too.  This can be useful if you share the files with (ugh!) Windows somehow.

A little editorializing: the two-byte end-of-line token chosed for MS-DOS has got to have been one of the biggest problems that MS-DOS foisted off on the world, after segments, drive-letters and "\" as directory seperator. That two-byte token is still the reason for a difference between "text" and "binary".  Ickk.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`find . -type f | xargs -I {} dos2unix {}`