# Not able to cat a string from a file under a string of another file

Tags: cat, newlines

I have encountered a strange issue in concatenating the files using the `cat` command. I have two files with one string in each of them:

file1:

```
ABC
```

file2:

```
DEF
```

Either I do `cat file1 file2` or I do `cat file1 >> file2`. I expect an output as shown below:

```
ABC  
DEF
```

However, I have a funny output like this:

```
ABCDEF
```

I have checked the files and there is no extra space or characters. However, when I do manual deleting from the back of the string, I don't even see a single character. It works fine. I suppose there must be some kind of "hidden" character or line which I can't see.

It has been bugging me a lot because I have tons of files to concatenate. I can't do the same thing manually.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `file1` does not have a trailing newline `\n` - (perhaps `file2` is the same).  Test `file1` via:  `hexdump file1`, and look for  `0a` at the end. `0a` is the hexadecimal value of the newline character

Comment: `ed "$file" <<< w` will write trailing new lines to a file lacking one.

Answer (score 5):

`paste` is probably the easiest *(which is not to mention extremely efficient)* means at your disposal to handle this problem.

```sh
printf abc >file1
printf def >file2
paste -sd\\n file[12]
```

---

```
abc
def
```

When `paste` is invoked `-s`erially it will read each of its named input files in-turn and `paste` the output of each line within each file on either a <tab> or a specified `-d`elimiter string. While `paste` will always end its output of each named infile with a `\n`ewline, here the `-d`elimiter is also specified to be a `\n`ewline, and so it will just basically `cat` its input to output with the exception that each file will always end in a `\n`ewline.

---

As Peter points out below, an empty file can cause `paste` to emit an extra `\n`ewline though. If this is an issue, practically the same method might be applied with `sed` which will *not* do so:

```sh
: > file0
sed '' file[012]
```

---

```
abc
def
```

Now with this method, though, *(with GNU `sed` at least)* there may be a different problem. Any `sed` will *always* write out a `\n`ewline before pulling in another line, but if it is the *very* last line of the whole concatenated series of input files, then some `sed`s *(such as GNU)* may *not* append a newline at the end. For example, with my input files, the *def* is not followed on by a newline.

And if *that* is a problem, well...

```sh
sed '' file[012] | paste -sd\\n
```

...the above pipeline should probably cover all your bases.

Comment: Great!  - with one caveat: an empty file will introduce a spurious blank line into the output. +1

Answer (score 1):

As Peter says, you first file does not have an end-of-line character. You can probably check it with `ls -l` --- if it's exactly three chars, this is it.

If you want to "cat" the files adding a newline *only* if the newline wasn't there, you can use the nice trick explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31955/52205).

If you have this three files:

```
[romano:~/tmp] % ls -l f1 f2 f3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 romano romano 3 Jul 12 14:58 f1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 romano romano 4 Jul 12 15:03 f2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 romano romano 4 Jul 12 15:03 f3
[romano:~/tmp] % cat f1 f2 f3
ABCDEF
GHI
```

where `f1` has no end-of-line in the last line, while the others do, you can just do:

```
[romano:~/tmp] % sed -e '$a\' f1 f2 f3
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

... `sed` is a Stream EDitor, and you are instructing it to print all unchanged and the last line adding nothing --- but `sed` implicitly add a newline when operates, so it solves the problem.

Notice that just using the `cat` + `echo` thing will add a newline *always*. so you'll have two where you had one:

```
[romano:~/tmp] % for i in f?; do cat $i; echo; done;
ABC
DEF

GHI

[romano:~/tmp] %
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `file1` has no trailing newline.  If you want to concatenate a list of files. You can first check each one and `cat` a newline where needed, as follows:

```
# make some sample files
printf "%s\n" abc > file1  
printf "%s"   def > file2  # no trailing newline
printf "%s\n" ghi > file3
printf "%s"   jkl > file4  # no trailing newline
```

---

```
# find files to concatenate and build a sorted array `f[]`
unset f i; 
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' path; do f[i++]="$path"
done < <(find . -type f -name 'file[0-9]' -print0 | sort -z)

# build the `cat` command
cmd=cat
tmp="$(mktemp)"; echo >$tmp   # a file which contains only `\n`
for file in "${f[@]}"; do
    lasthex=$(tail -c1 $file | hexdump -ve '1/1 "%02x"')
    [[ -z $lasthex ]] && continue     # skip enpty files
    [[ $lasthex == 0a ]] && nl= || nl=" $tmp"
    cmd="$cmd \"$file\"$nl"
done

# execute the `cat` command
eval "$cmd"
```

---

The concatenated result is:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

The generated command is:

```
cat "./file1" "./file2" /tmp/tmp.z7iKccY0T9 "./file3" "./file4" /tmp/tmp.z7iKccY0T9
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missing newlines. You could do

```
cat file1; echo; cat file2;
```

or create a file which has only one linebrake and do

```
cat file1 NEWLINEFILE file2
```

or do this with a loop like this

```
for i in find[1-2]; do cat $i; echo; done;
```

to run through *, cat each file and add a newline afterwards.

With `$(find OPTIONS)` instead of `find[1-2]`, you could refine your selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can see special characters in a file with `od -c filename`.  Newlines will look like `\n`.  If Windows or source control changed the newlines, you will see `\r\n` using `od -c`, but you won't see anything different with `cat`. You can use `dos2unix filename` to repair those.

Sometimes you will see a sequence of control characters that cat would print out to look like a "-" or some other valid character.

Comment: The suggestion to use `od` to inspect files is indeed a good one. I removed the part about this not being an answer because it doesn't add anything useful (on Stack Exchange sites, answers that aren't answers should be deleted). Also, note that this question deals with files not ending in a newline, which aren't usually related to file conversion across platforms - tools as `dos2unix` won't actually help in this case.