# Force newlines with cat wildcard printing

Tags: bash, wildcards, cat, newlines

I want to use cat with wildcards in bash in order to print multiple small files (every file is one sentence) to standard output. However, the separate file contents are not separated by a newline, which I'd like to for ease of reading.

How can I add a file delimiter of some sort to this command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Define a shell function which outputs an end of line after every file and use it instead of `cat`:

```
endlcat() {
  for file in "$@"; do
    cat -- "$file"
    echo
  done
}
```

then you can use `endlcat *`.

The `for` loop loops over all provided arguments (`$@`) which are already escaped by the shell when you use wildcards like `*`. The `--` is required to not choke on file names starting with a dash. Finally the `echo` outputs a newline.

Comment: It seems rather obvious to use iteration in hindsight! I thought there might have been a flag in cat, but this works too! Thank you.

Comment: You don't need the `in "$@"` - it's implicit.

Comment: being explicit is good for readability.

Answer (score 7):

Just use a loop instead of simple `cat`:

```
for file in /path/to/targetdir/*; do
    echo "-------- $file -------"
    cat "$file" 
done
```

Comment: Works like the accepted answer, but that one also had the next step to the commandline so I accepted the other one.

Answer (score 4):

If you want file name between files, using `tail`:

```
tail -n +1 ./*
```

(In case you want `tac` instead of `cat`, some `tail` implementation have `-r` option for equivalent `tac` functional)

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
sed '' -- *
```

You don't need any shell loops or otherwise, and this will always follow the output of a file with a `\n`ewline - excepting perhaps the very last.

Otherwise if you want a *blank* line to be output between the output of each file, this could work:

```
bpaste(){
    eval "paste -'sd\n' -- $(x=0;for f do printf "\"\${$((x+=1))}\" - ";done)"
}   </dev/null
```

That will always follow the output of a file with a `\n`ewline *and* an additional *blank* line.

You can call it like:

```
bpaste *
```

Comment: @cuonglm - the op wants a newline between files. this ensures a newline between files.

Comment: @cuonglm - you should try again. `for n in 1 2 3; do printf "$n" >"$n"; done; sed '' -- [123]`

Comment: @cuonglm - any `sed` must always print a `\n`ewline before it prints anything else, the last line of the *last* file might not get a `\n`ewline appended though. i could swear ive answered this question before.

Comment: @cuonglm - i dont understand what you mean. that little bit of shell i just gave you prints `1\n2\n3`. it works. it always does. what does it print for you?

Comment: @cuonglm - thats not the question. the op said theres no newline between files he/she `cat`s together - presumably because they dont end with a `\n`ewline. so this just adds one if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: @cuonglm - that wouldn't do a blank line if the files didnt end in newlines.

Comment: @cuonglm - look - `printf 1|{ cat; echo; }` - no blank line. if the input files dont end in `\n`ewlines this solution works exactly the same as the accepted answer, only it doesn't need to call `cat` once per file and doesnt do any unnecessary shell loops. if the op wants a blank line between the contents of each file he/she certainly didnt indicate it.

Comment: Right, maybe we need to ask the OP for clarity.

Comment: _"I could swear I've answered this question before"_ - not the same Q but a very similar one: [Join multiple files with two blank lines?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204224)

Comment: @don_crissti - no. that wasnt the one i was thinking of, but i guess i answered that, too.

Comment: @don_crissti - [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/215416/52934) is the one i was thinking of. its in the link list on the side, too.

Comment: `sed '$s/$/\n/' -- *` will replace the end of the last line of the last file (which might be a newline or it might be nothing) with a newline. Otherwise, it acts like the `sed` command in the answer. Similarly, `awk '1' -- *` does the same thing (the `1` is "true" which causes a `print`). If you want an extra newline between each file and you have GAWK 4: `awk '{print} ENDFILE {print ""}' -- *`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Using `\n` in RHS isn't standard. You can use `sed -e '$G'`.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [@terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236105/44356)'s answer, if you happen to prefer seeing the filename in the future as well, you can use the `head` command:

```
$ head *file*
==> file_1 <==
file 1 content

==> file_2 <==
file 2 content

==> file_3 <==
file 3 content
```

`head` defaults to first 10 lines, so using it without command options for your case (one sentence per file) is perfectly fine. Otherwise, you need the `-n X` option.

Answer (score 2):

Another way - use `grep -h` to simply search for the empty string in each file. This will match all lines, regardless of how many or whether newline-terminated or not.  grep results are always newline-terminated.  The `-h` option suppresses prefixing each line of output with the filename it came from:

```
$ printf 'a' > a
$ printf 'b\nB' > b
$ printf 'c\n' > c
$ ls
a  b  c
$ cat -- *
ab
Bc
$ grep -h '' *
a
b
B
c
$
```

---

Or you could use GNU `paste` in `-s`erial mode with newline as the delimiter:

```
$ paste -s -d '\n' -- *
a
b
B
c
$
```