# How to cat files together, adding missing newlines at end of some files

Tags: shell, text-processing, cat, newlines

I have a bunch of `.text` files, *most* of which end with the standard nl.

A couple don't have any terminator at end.  The last physical byte is (generally) an alphameric character.

I was using `cat *.text >| /tmp/joined.text`, but then noticed a couple of places in joined.text where the first line of a file appeared at the end of the last line of a previous file.  Inspecting the previous file, I saw there wasn't a line terminator -- concatenation explained.

That raised the question, what's the easiest way to concatenate, sticking in the missing newline? What about these options?

1. A solution that might effectively add a blank line to some input files.  For me, that's not a problem as the processing of joined.text can handle it.
2. A solution that adds the cr/fl only to files that do not already end that way.

Comment: Safest is to add the missing newline e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file?rq=1 Totally unsafe is leaving those broken files around then wondering why a shell `while` is skipping those broken last lines.

Comment: Do you really want a cr/lf or do you want the normal, standard `\n`? On *nix systems, lines end with a single `\n`. The `\r\n` is a Windows thing. And where do you want this? At the end of each line? The end of the file?

Comment: @thrig But which specific files?  In other words, what's a good way to automatically identify them (instead of opening each and every candidate)?  And if another one gets accidentally generated, then an automated method would be extra nice!

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the catch.  My windows heritage shows...  The nl goes only at the end of a file that doesn't have one.  Each lines in a multi-line file ends with nl, except for the last.  Probably because some editor dropped it.

Comment: @terdon that idea would work for Option 1, however the way I read the find man, '%s\n' would append the size of the file.  Probably want just '\n'?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `find`; yes, in `find`, the `%s` of `printf` is the size of the file. But that's a peculiarity of `find`. The `printf` utility is very standard and exists (behaving more or less the same way) in shells and most programming languages. There, `printf '%s' foo` will just replace the `%s` with `foo` and print it.

Answer (score 37):

Another command that can add newlines if needed is `awk`, so:

```
awk 1 ./*.txt
```

The 1 here is the simplest way to get a true condition in awk, which works for this purpose since awk default action on true conditions is to print the input lines.

Comment: Hi @muru, can u explain a bit what does "awk 1" mean?

Comment: @Jon awk's default action on true conditions is to print the input lines, and `1` is the simplest true condition. It's shorthand for `awk '{print}'`

Answer (score 5):

This handy Perl one-liner can do the job of adding the missing newline only if not already there:

```
perl -lpe '' ./*.text > output
```

Answer (score 5):

With some `cut` implementations like GNU `cut`, you can do:

```
cut -b 1- ./*.text > output
```

as it will add the missing newline if missing.

Comment: works. my usecase: ` cut -b 1- *.json`

Answer (score 5):

You could use this:

```
grep -h "" ./*.txt
```

-h will remove the filename printout

Comment: best answer!!!!

Comment: best answer by far... cannot be done in a simpler way (may to complete the answer should add the "> new_file.txt"  string at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach that comes to mind is to loop over the files and just print their contents with an appended newline:

```
for f in *text; do
    printf '%s\n' "$(cat < "$f")"
done > /tmp/joined.text
```

The `$()` will strip any already existing newline characters so this will result in just one `\n` at the end of each file.

Comment: Don't want to strip existing NLs -- that would just run all the lines together, compounding my problem.  What I hear you telling me is for Option 1, just loop through all the files, printing each one then a NL.  I'm noobie surprised that isn't something in an existing utility to force a new line when necessary so lines don't run together.

Comment: @HiTechHiTouch this will both remove any existing `\n` *and* add one. The result will always be one (and only one) `\n` at the end of each file. The `%s` is a `printf` thing, it just means "string". See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string). You are confusing it with the `[ -s file ]` which is the size of the file. This does both option 1 and option 2. As for a utility, no there isn't because any program that writes to a file always adds a newline. If there isn't one, that is almost always because something broke and the file is corrupted.

Comment: Note that it adds an empty line for empty files (or files that can't be opened for reading). In shells other than `zsh`, it will choke on NUL characters. It should probably also be noted that it loads the whole files in memory.