# How to add a newline to a "no-text returned" from ssh command

Tags: centos, scripting

Within a Qt5 application I have a bash script which runs to check version numbers from certain files on other remote machines (that I ssh into).

I have over 100 machines that I can run this script on. If the machine I have sshed into has the file I am looking for the script output is nicely displayed, but if the file on the remote machine does not exist then my 2 lines join together.

e.g

Should look like this:

```
Operating System: 1.5.64 
sw_install: 1.16
Kate 1.1
```

but if remote files don't exist I get

```
Operating System:  sw_install
Kate: 1.1
```

Any ideas to get the lines to be separate if the remote files don't exist (if does happen). I don't just want to put an 'echo' line in between the 2 ssh commands (or remove the -n) as the output is not the desired look when the files do exist.

Hoping there is a really simple answer out there please.

Thank you very much for your help!!

```
echo -n "Operating System: "
ssh -t -o LogLevel=QUIET -o '''StrictHostKeyChecking no''' $NODENAME "cat /home/user/Version.txt"
echo -n "sw_intall: "
ssh -t -o LogLevel=QUIET -o '''StrictHostKeyChecking no''' $NODENAME "grep VERSION= /home/user/sw_install | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\"' |  head -1"
ssh -t -o LogLevel=QUIET -o '''StrictHostKeyChecking no''' $NODENAME "rpm -qv kate --qf \"         Kate:  %{VERSION}.%{RELEASE}\""
```

Centos 7.2

Comment: It should work if you remove the `-n` and put the ssh command into a command substitution like `echo "Operating System: $(ssh -t …)"`. I'm just wondering why don't get an error message if the file is missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cat files together, adding missing newlines at end of some files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345548/how-to-cat-files-together-adding-missing-newlines-at-end-of-some-files)

Comment: Freddy, I think there is no error message because what is being returned is stdout not stderr so I get nothing...

Comment: I have added "|| echo unknown version" to the cat line and get the correct answer. This solution doesn't work for the grep line though...

Comment: How about supressing the error with `grep -s` and catching the empty string like this: `VERSION=$(grep -s VERSION= /home/user/sw_install | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\"' |  head -1);echo ${VERSION:="no-text returned"}`

Comment: Btw, I don't know the very format of your `sw_install` file, but all your piping and `grep`ing and `cut`ting and `tr`ing and `head`ing can probably be replaced by a simple `sed '/.*VERSION=/!d;s///;s/[\"]//g;q'`

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe cat to `tr -d '\n'` and explicitly add a newline after the command.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `echo` at all. Use `printf` and add the newline explicitly. Change this:

```
echo -n "Operating System: "
ssh -t -o LogLevel=QUIET -o '''StrictHostKeyChecking no''' $NODENAME "cat /home/user/Version.txt"
echo -n "sw_intall: "
ssh -t -o LogLevel=QUIET -o '''StrictHostKeyChecking no''' $NODENAME "grep VERSION= /home/user/sw_install | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\"' |  head -1"
ssh -t -o LogLevel=QUIET -o '''StrictHostKeyChecking no''' $NODENAME "rpm -qv kate --qf \"         Kate:  %{VERSION}.%{RELEASE}\""
```

To this:

```
os=$(ssh -t -o LogLevel=QUIET -o '''StrictHostKeyChecking no''' $NODENAME "cat /home/user/Version.txt")
swInstall=$(ssh -t -o LogLevel=QUIET -o '''StrictHostKeyChecking no''' $NODENAME "grep VERSION= /home/user/sw_install | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\"' |  head -1")
kate=$(ssh -t -o LogLevel=QUIET -o '''StrictHostKeyChecking no''' $NODENAME "rpm -qv kate --qf \"         Kate:  %{VERSION}.%{RELEASE}\"")

printf 'Operating System: %s\nsw_intall: %s\nKate: %s\n' "$os" "$swInstall" "$kate"
```

Alternatively, use a heredoc:

```
cat<<EoF
Operating System: $(ssh -t -o LogLevel=QUIET -o '''StrictHostKeyChecking no''' $NODENAME "cat /home/user/Version.txt")
sw_install: $(ssh -t -o LogLevel=QUIET -o '''StrictHostKeyChecking no''' $NODENAME "grep VERSION= /home/user/sw_install | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\"' |  head -1")
Kate: $(ssh -t -o LogLevel=QUIET -o '''StrictHostKeyChecking no''' $NODENAME "rpm -qv kate --qf \"         Kate:  %{VERSION}.%{RELEASE}\"")
EoF
```

Comment: Thank you Terdon, that first option worked nicely.