# Read a line-oriented file which may not end with a newline

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, newlines

I have a file named `/tmp/urlFile` where each line represents a url. I am trying to read from the file as follows:

```
cat "/tmp/urlFile" | while read url
do
    echo $url
done
```

If the last line doesn't end with a newline character, that line won't be read. I was wondering why?

Is it possible to read all the lines, regardless if they are ended with a new line or not?

Comment: It's discussed at [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) (with some way to do it)

Comment: Another way to add the trailing newline if it's missing; `awk 1 /tmp/urlFile` .. so `awk 1 /tmp/urlFile | while ...`

Comment: Since you’re asking *why* it isn’t read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/729795/1968

Answer (score 32):

You'd do:

```
while IFS= read -r url || [ -n "$url" ]; do
  printf '%s\n' "$url"
done < url.list
```

(effectively, that loop adds back the missing newline on the last (non-)line).

See also:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)
- [Understand "IFS= read -r line"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: Thanks. I read the linked articles, and maybe I miss something, why "that loop adds back the missing newline on the last (non-)line"?

Comment: @Tim  What Stephane seems to mean is that it adds back the missing newline in the output since all `printf` calls here have `\n` .

Comment: This is really clever. If the input does _not_ end in a newline, then it must be the last/only line, so as long as it's not completely empty, we still want to process it. I suspect this could also work with `read -r url || :` instead, but then (I think) you'd always get an empty string at the very end of a file that does in fact end in `\n`.

Comment: @shadowtalker `read -r url || :` is always true, so the loop would never end and you'd keep printing empty lines after the end of the input is reached.

Comment: Of course, that's silly of me.

Answer (score 8):

Well, `read` returns a falsy value if it meets end-of-file before a newline, but even if it does, it still assigns the value it read. So, we can check if the final call of `read` returns something else than an empty line, and process it as normal. So, only exit the loop after `read` returns false *and* the line is empty:

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r line || [ "$line" ]; do 
    echo "line: $line"
done

$ printf 'foo\nbar' | sh ./read.sh 
line: foo
line: bar
$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' | sh ./read.sh 
line: foo
line: bar
```

Answer (score 7):

By [definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403), a text file consists of a sequence of lines. A [line](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) ends with a newline character. Thus a text file ends with a newline character, unless it's empty.

The `read` builtin is only meant to read text files. You aren't passing a text file, so you can't hope it to work seamlessly. The shell reads all the lines — what it's skipping are the extra characters after the last line.

If you have a potentially malformed input file that may be missing its last line, you could add a newline to it, just to be sure.

```
{ cat "/tmp/urlFile"; echo; } | …
```

Files that should be text files but are missing the final newline are often produced by Windows editors. This usually goes in combination with Windows line endings, which are CR LF, as opposed to Unix's LF. CR characters are rarely useful anywhere, and can't appear in URLs in any case, so you should remove them.

```
{ <"/tmp/urlFile" tr -d '\r'; echo; } | …
```

In case the input file is well-formed and does end with a newline, the `echo` adds an extra blank line. Since URLs can't be empty, just ignore blank lines.

Note also that `read` does not read lines in a straightforward way. It ignores leading and trailing whitespace, which for a URL is probably desirable. It treats backslash at the end of a line as an escape character, causing the next line to be joined with the first minus the backslash-newline sequence, which is definitely not desirable. So you should pass the `-r` option to `read`. It is very, very rare for `read` to be the right thing rather than `read -r`.

```
{ <"/tmp/urlFile" tr -d '\r'; echo; } | while read -r url
do
  if [ -z "$url" ]; then continue; fi
  …
done
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be solved in part with `readarray -t`:

```
readarray -t urls "/tmp/urlFile"
for url in "${urls[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$url"
done
```

Note however that while this does work for reasonably-sized files, this solution introduces a potential new problem with very large files - it first reads the file into an array which then must be iterated through. For very large files this could be both time- and memory-consuming, potentially to the point of failure.

Comment: Thanks. Which part does it solve and which does it not?

Comment: It solves the problem with the lack of a trailing newline, but introduces a potential new problem with very large files, because it first reads the file into an array which then must be iterated through.

Comment: @DopeGhoti That's good information - can I suggest you add it directly into the answer?

Comment: Tha answer has been so amended.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be like this :

> When read reaches end-of-file instead of end-of-line, it does read in
>   the data and assign it to the variables, but it exits with a non-zero
>   status. If your loop is constructed "while read ;do stuff ;done
>
> So instead of testing the read exit status directly, test a flag, and
>   have the read command set that flag from within the loop body. That
>   way regardless of reads exit status, the entire loop body runs,
>   because read was just one of the list of commands in the loop like any
>   other, not a deciding factor of if the loop will get run at all.

```
DONE=false
until $DONE ;do
read || DONE=true
echo $REPLY 
done < /tmp/urlFile
```

Referred from [here](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/SuSE/2008-11/msg00237.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
cat "/tmp/urlFile" | while read url
do
    echo $url
done
```

This is a [Useless Use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org./era/unix/award.html#cat).

Ironically, you can replace the `cat` process here with something actually useful: a tool that POSIX systems have for adding the missing newline, and making the file into a proper POSIX text file.

```
sed -e '$a\' "/tmp/urlFile" | while read -r url
do
    printf "%s\n" "${url}"
done
```

## Further reading

- [How to add a newline to the end of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/)

Comment: The behaviour of sed is unspecified by POSIX when the input doesn't end in a newline character though; also when there are lines larger than LINE_MAX, while the behaviour of `read` is specified in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

To read all the lines, regardless if they are ended with a new line or not:

```
cat "/tmp/urlFile" | { cat ; echo ; } | while read url; do echo $url; done
```

Source : My open source project https://sourceforge.net/projects/command-output-to-html-table/