# Why does this 'while' loop not recognize the last line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, rhel

We use the following script:

```
more test.sh
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do

echo $line

done < /tmp/file
```

This is the file:

```
kafka-broker,log.retention.hours,12
kafka-broker,default.replication.factor,2
fefolp-defaults,fefolp.history.fs.cleaner.interval,1d
fefolp-defaults,fefolp.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge,2d
fefolp-env,fefolp_daemon_memory,10000
blo-site,blo.nodemanager.localizer.cache.target-size-mb,10240
blo-site,blo.nodemanager.localizer.cache.cleanup.interval-ms,300000
ams-env,metrics_collector_heapsize,512
fefolp,hbase_master_heapsize,1408
fefolp,hbase_regionserver_heapsize,512
fefolp,hbase_master_xmn_size,192
core-site,blolp.proxyuser.ambari.hosts,*
core-site,Hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups,*
core-site,Hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts,*
blo-site,blo.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb,1024
blolp-env,fefolp_heapsize,4096
```

Remark - after the last line - there are no space!

But the script prints only these lines (except the last line):

```
./test.sh
kafka-broker,log.retention.hours,12
kafka-broker,default.replication.factor,2
fefolp-defaults,fefolp.history.fs.cleaner.interval,1d
fefolp-defaults,fefolp.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge,2d
fefolp-env,fefolp_daemon_memory,10000
blo-site,blo.nodemanager.localizer.cache.target-size-mb,140
blo-site,blo.nodemanager.localizer.cache.cleanup.interval-ms,300
ams-env,metrics_collector_heapsize,51
fefolp,hbase_master_heapsize,1408
fefolp,hbase_regionserver_heapsize,542
fefolp,hbase_master_xmn_size,19
core-site,blolp.proxyuser.ambari.hosts,*
core-site,Hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups,*
core-site,Hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts,*
blo-site,blo.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb,1024
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: because the last text line is not complete. you need a \n there.

Comment: do you have suggestion how to add \n on the last line in the file , so I will put thus in the scritp

Comment: echo >> file as a poor mans solution.

Comment: Note POSIX [defines "line"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) as `a sequence of zero or more non- <newline> characters plus a terminating <newline> character`. Your last line isn't even a line in this context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read a line-oriented file which may not end with a newline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418060/read-a-line-oriented-file-which-may-not-end-with-a-newline)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your input text contains an incomplete line as its last line. The last line is not terminated by a newline.

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done <file
```

The above loop will read unmodified lines¹ (without stripping whitespaces or interpreting backslashed control sequences) from the file called `file` and print them to standard output.

When an *incomplete* line is read, `read` will fail, but `$line` will still contain data.  The extra `-n` test will detect this so that the loop body is allowed to output the incomplete line.  In the iteration after that, `read` will fail again and `$line` will be an empty string, thus terminating the loop.

---

<sup>¹ assuming they don't contain NUL characters in shells other than `zsh` and assuming they don't contain sequences of bytes not forming part of valid characters in the `yash` shell, both of which shouldn't happen if the input is valid text, though that missing line delimiter on the last line already makes it invalid text.</sup>

Comment: the script is only example of the problem , actually I set the echo in the script to show this issue , but what we need is how to set the last line with "\n" with sed for example, since the the - file is already exists

Comment: so if need to add "\n on the last line , then need sed/perl to add the "\" for this solution

Comment: @yael You say in the question that you use a loop like the one you are showing. I gave a solution for how to fix that loop.  It does not matter what the body of the loop looks like, `$line` will be each individual line of the file, including the last incomplete one.  If you don't use a loop like this, what do you use?

Comment: ok , so maybe I will post another question for how to add "\n" on the last line

Comment: @yael [How to add a newline to the end of a file?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/31947)

Comment: thank you so much my friend I am really appreciate it

Comment: @Kusalananda Could you please also answer this one with a nearly identical answer? https://superuser.com/questions/1500525/reason-for-behind-read

Answer (score -1):

Input to the while read loop must be done like this :

```
cat /tmp/file | { cat ; echo ; } | while read -r line; do echo $line;  done
```

This will process all lines, including the last one.

Source : My open source project https://sourceforge.net/projects/command-output-to-html-table/

Comment: Just do `{ cat /tmp/file; echo; }` if you're going to do that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418081/70524

Comment: We could use any outputting program instead of cat /tmp/file hence the given structure / syntax.

Comment: Yes, you could use any program: `{ foo ; echo; } | ...`

Comment: This would add an extra empty line to any file whose last line _is_ properly terminated by a newline character.

Comment: @Kusalananda
But the question is "How to make the 'while' loop recognize the last line?" and my answer solves the problem !

Comment: @NathanSR No, because if you are trying to read the last line from a file that has a properly terminated last line already, this would give you an empty line as the result, not the last line of the file.  Yes, you would get the last line from your compound command, but that would not be the last line from `foo` if `foo` properly terminates the last line.

Answer (score -1):

Following *Your input text contains an incomplete line as its last line. The last line is not terminated by a newline.* Leave the loop as is and simply make sure there is a return for the variable line.

```bash
while read -r i
do
#
line="$(echo "$i"| sed 's/$/@/'| tr '\n' '@'|sed 's/@@/@/' |tr '@' '\n')"
#
echo $line
#
done < /tmp/file
```

You can change the `@` to anything you like.

Comment: This does not work because the `read` call will fail upon reading the incomplete line and the body of the `if`-statement will therefore not be executed for that data.  Additionally, this would replace any occurrence of `@` in the data with a newline, and may also expand `\t` and `\n` and other backslash-sequences depending on what shell options are set.  It will also not retain tabs or proper spacing (tabs will be changed to spaces, and multiple consecutive spaces will be combined), and will apply filename globbing on the text (due to the unquoted use of `$line` with your secord `echo`).