# Bash Read: Reading comma separated list, last element is missed

Tags: bash, shell-script, read, shell-builtin

The output of the command below is weird to me. Why does it not give me back element 5?

```
$ echo '0,1,2,3,4,5' | while read -d, i; do echo $i; done
0
1
2
3
4
```

I would expect '5' to be returned as well. Running `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`. Adding a comma works, but my input data does not have a comma. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `read`, `-d` is used to *terminate* the input lines (i.e. not to separate input lines). Your last "line" contains no terminator, so `read` returns false on EOF and the loop exits (even though the final value was read).

```
echo '0,1,2,3,4,5' | { while read -d, i; do echo "$i"; done; echo "last value=$i"; }
```

(Even with `-d`, `read` also uses `$IFS`, absorbing whitespace including the trailing `\n` on the final value that would appear using other methods such as `readarray`)

The Bash FAQ discusses this, and how to handle various similar cases:

- [Bash Pitfalls #47 *IFS=, read [...]*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#IFS.3D.2C_read_-ra_fields_.3C.3C.3C_.22.24csv_line.22)
- [BashFAQ 001 *How can I read a file [...] line-by-line*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
- [BashFAQ 005 *How can I use array variables?*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Handling_newlines_.28or_lack_thereof.29_at_the_end_of_a_file)

Comment: I guess one could do `read -d, i || [[ -n $i ]]` a la [What does `while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]` mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478720/what-does-while-read-r-line-n-line-mean)

Answer (score 8):

As other answers state, `-d` is an end-of-line character, not a field separator.  You can do

```
IFS=, read -a fields <<< "1,2,3,4,5"
for i in "${fields[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 5):

From man:

> -d delim
>
> The first character of delim is used to terminate the input line, rather than newline.

Your element 5 doesn't have a delimiter (comma), so it won't be read.

Comment: So the best fix is putting another comma after the input?

Comment: The [best fix might be to process data with something other than a shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/117549). Since the answerers here have addressed the current question, you might consider a separate question that demonstrates your larger goal.

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is the same behavior (and for the same reason) as [Why does this 'while' loop not recognize the last line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482517/why-does-this-while-loop-not-recognize-the-last-line)

As in that case, you can modify the behavior by adding an extra test to the loop termination condition, as follows

```
while read -d, i || [[ -n $i ]]; do ...
```

Ex.

```
$ echo '0,1,2,3,4,5' | while read -d, i || [[ -n $i ]]; do echo $i; done
0
1
2
3
4
5
```