# new line not append instead append on the end of the line

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

we gave the following config file ( config.txt )

```
more config.txt
export var1=345476746
```

but when I am appending new parameter as

```
echo "export var2=5645" >> config.txt
```

we get

```
more config.txt
export var1=345476746export var2=5645
```

how to avoid this?

so we get

```
more config.txt
export var1=345476746
export var2=5645
```

Comment: `config.txt` has no [newline at the end of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline). Fix that or simply add one before adding `var2`.

Comment: still not understand how to add "\n" on each line , seems that last line isn't with "\n"

Comment: If your text file is generated by common text editors in Unix, there should be a newline in the end of the file because that is required by the POSIX standard. In `vim`, files without `\n` in the last line is indicated in the status line by `[noeol]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a newline to the end of a file?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/31947)

Comment: See also [What's the point in adding a new line to the end of a file?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/18743)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `config.txt` has no newline at the end of the file.

The [posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) says [there should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline):

> **3.206 Line**
>   A sequence of zero or more non-  characters **plus a terminating <newline> character**.

You can [add a new line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file), e.g.:

```
sed -i -e '$a\' config.txt
```

This will add a new line only when there is not already one at the end.

In your case a simple `echo >> config.txt` would do the job.

Comment: A simple `echo >> config.txt` should do the work if it is just missing the final `\n`.

Comment: In this case yes, but it will append a newline if it's missing or not.

Comment: It's quite inefficient though and is not without side effect (like breaking symlinks, hardlinks, possibly changing file owership)  as it makes full copy of the file.

Comment: @Stéphane, If you have a better idea, you could post it on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file, or comment on the highest voted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should have inserted the text `export var1=345476746` with `-n` option initially.

> -n   `do not output the trailing newline`

Example :

```
echo -n "export var1=345476746" > config.txt
echo "export var2=5645" >> config.txt
```

Results :

```
# more config.txt 
export var1=345476746export var2=5645
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add a newline char is with echo.

```
echo >> config.txt
echo "export var2=5645" >> config.txt
```