# Is there a way to count the number of lines of text in a file including non-delimited ones?

Tags: newlines, wc, line

The POSIX `wc` command counts how many POSIX lines in a file. The POSIX standard defines a *line* as a text string with the suffix `\n`. Without `\n`, a pure text string can't be called a line.

But to me, it's more natural to count how many lines of text string in a file. Is there an easy way to do that?

```
root:[~]# printf "aa\nbb" | wc -l
1
root:[~]# printf "aa\nbb\n" | wc -l
2
root:[~]#
```

Comment: Related: [How to add a newline to the end of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31947/86440) (when the file doesn’t already have one).

Answer (score 7):

With GNU `sed`, you can use:

```
sed '$=;d'
```

As GNU `sed` does consider those extra characters after the last newline as an extra line. GNU `sed` like most GNU utilities also supports NUL characters in its input and doesn't have a limitation on the length of lines (the two other criteria that make an input non-text as per POSIX).

POSIXLy, building-up on [@Inian's answer](/a/535311) to support too-long lines and NUL bytes:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -cs '\n' '[x*]' | awk 'END {print NR}'
```

That `tr` command translates all sequences of one or more character (each byte interpreted as a character in the C locale to avoid decoding issues) other than newline to *one* `x` character, so `awk` input records will be either 0 or 1 byte long and its input contain only `x` and newline characters.

```
$ printf '%10000s\na\0b\nc\nd' | wc -l
3

$ printf '%10000s\na\0b\nc\nd' | mawk 'END{print NR}'
2
$ printf '%10000s\na\0b\nc\nd' | busybox awk 'END{print NR}'
5
$ printf '%10000s\na\0b\nc\nd' | gawk 'END{print NR}'
4

$ printf '%10000s\na\0b\nc\nd' | LC_ALL=C tr -cs '\n' '[x*]' | mawk 'END{print NR}'
4
```

Comment: Under which conditions will `tr -cs '\n' 'x'` fail ?

Comment: @Isaac, while `tr -cs '\n' 'x'` would also work with the `tr` of GNU or some BSDs, it is not POSIX as POSIX leaves the behaviour unspecified when the second set (here `x`) is shorter than the first (here the complement of `\n`). It won't work in SysV-derived `tr` implementations for instance. `[x*]` means _as many x as necessary to fill-up the set_.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `awk` for this which has a special variable `NR` which tracks the number of current record from the start of the file. The variable gets incremented at the end of each line. When printed at the `END` block i.e. after all the input lines are processed it prints the number of the last record processed.

```
printf "aa\nbb" | awk 'END { print NR }'
2

printf "aa\nbb\n" | awk 'END { print NR }'
2
```

Comment: Note that with some `awk` implementations, that still implies the input doesn't contain NUL characters (which would also make that input non-text as per POSIX).