# How to fix linux text files with no newline or EOF?

Tags: linux, text

I need to write a "find" exec command to awk print formatted results to some existing text files.
In some odd scenario, I would get lines appended on the previous last line (no CR after LF?), not on a new line.
How could I prevent this from happening? is there any command I could fix the text files before the append? dos2unix?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31955/70524

Comment: Have you checked (for example with `hexdump -C filename`) what the problem really is? Linux just uses LF as a line separator, so it can't be "no CR after LF". Editing your question with the commands you use, an example of a file where it goes wrong and what results you get would help.

Comment: @dirkt if a unix file is not terminated by a newline, it's technically not a text file, and many Unix tools working on text files are allowed to "misbehave", and will misbehave (the most notorious being the `read` shell builtin: `printf hello | read q || echo not read, why?`. An easy way for me to create such broken non-text files is by copy-pasting via the GUI ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
awk 1 file1 file2 ... > outfile
```

instead of `cat file1 file2 ... > outfile`
The only problem is that unlike `cat`, `awk` will immediately exit with an error if it cannot open and read any of `file1`, `file2`, etc, instead of continuing with the rest of the files. If that's a problem, on most modern systems you can use `grep ''` as already suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322805/414777) + the `-h` option to omit the filenames (though beware that this is exploiting non-standard features of `grep`):

```
grep -h '' file1 file2 ... > outfile
```

Answer (score 1):

there's an interesting `hack` where you can format bash command with awk and push it to bash like so:

```
awk '{ print "find " $1 " -exec ls {} \;" }' ./source_file | bash
```

this will give you instant execution of commands such as:

```
find /var -exec ls {} \;
find /home/user1 -exec ls {} \;
# and so on depending on the contents of the ./source_file
```

hope this helps :)